# DateDiff in my VB.Net's RDLC Returns #error

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, rdlc

I'm working on an RDLC report in Visual Studio Pro 2013 Report Builder (VB). I have a function (below) using the `DateDiff()` function where the value results to `#error`:

```
=DateDiff("dd", Fields!DateFrom.Value, Parameters!pfDateTo.Value)
```

This gets the number of days from one of my fields compared to a parameter which is a `DateTime` datatype. No null values resulted in my query.

Am I missing something? How can I fix this?

thanks in advance.

here is the image that displays the dates
[image: here is the image that displays the dates]

Using one "d" results to 141?:
[Using one "d"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkFWt.jpg)

Comment: As an intermediate step, try showing both dates on the report instead of the difference. This may aid you in troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: i have attached an image that displays the dates but #error results on the formula for calculating the number of days between those two dates (date from and date to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just one `"d"` and make sure that the values are dates. This way it should work:

```
=DateDiff("d", CDate(Fields!DateFrom.Value), CDate(Parameters!pfDateTo.Value))
```

Comment: I have updated the question posting the result as per your suggestion.

Comment: Jep and this is the correct result? The difference in days from `12.03.2019` to `31.07.2019`is `141 days`. And you have in every row the same dates, so you get every time the same result.

Comment: oh sorry. yes its 141 because it's march.